# Javascript: redirect to new page based on radio button choice

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is redirect to a new page if the "yes" button is clicked. I already have a prompt set up if they click "no". However, there is a form (name and email) that needs to be filled out for this to work.  If they do not fill out these details, I want a prompt to arise telling the user that they need to fill them out before they can proceed.

I am fairly new to javascript so any tips or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the html code

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes"><strong>Yes, I agree.</strong> 
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" checked="checked"><strong>No, I do not agree.            </strong><br>
<br>    
If you agree, please enter your full name and email address in the spaces below and press   submit.
<br>
<form> Full Name:<input type="text" name="fullname"></form>
<br>  
<form> Email Address:<input type="text" name="email"></form>
<br>     
<br>
<form action="endPage.jsp" id="form">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And the javascript code

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
var termsChk = document.getElementById("yes");
var formFrm = document.getElementById("emailField");
var formFrm = document.getElementById("nameField");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (termsChk.checked === true && formFrm)

{
    alert("Checked!");
    formFrm.submit();
} else {
    alert("Please Contact Spearhead Mining Corporation: projects@spearheadmining.com to discuss your options for project submittal!");
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: Show the code for the form. Show the code for your "already set" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For a more specific answer it might help if you posted the code for yes and no buttons, as well as the HTML code for the form. That being said the way you would generally handle this is in the code for the yes button you run whatever client side validations you need to run, in this case checking if the name and email fields aren't empty, then displaying your error message instead of redirecting if everything is not valid.

For instance in your yes handler

```
if(document.getElementById('emailField').value == null || document.getElementById('namefield') == null){
  /*error handling code goes here*/
  return
 }
else{
  /*redirection code goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm) with the spcific message to user and use [window.location()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) to redirect to the new url.

```
result = window.confirm("Message to user");
if(result) {
     window.location = "new url";
} else {
     //do the rest of logic
}
```